# Find second-largest value within bounded window in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

SQL question - Does anyone know of a way to select the second-highest value from a bounded window? I have pricing data for a set of geographies/products/weeks. I need to create a new column that, for each row, shows the **second-highest price** offered for a given geo/product over the past 13 weeks. I basically need to find an NTH_ROW () equivalent in ADW. Ideally, the solution would look similar to the following but identify the 2nd-highest price rather than the max (unless there was only one week of pricing registered during the 13 wks, in which case it would populate that price):

```
    comparison_price = MAX(price) over (
                          PARTITION BY geography, product
                          ORDER BY week
                          ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

This image shows an example of what I would want the comparison_price column to populate for each week of a specific product/geo:

[image: Example Table]

I tried using an NROW() workaround, but received an error saying that the window needs to be unbounded. I've also considered creating a separate CTE but am trying to find a more elegant solution. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest approach might be a lateral join, and window functions:

```
select t.*, coalesce(x.price, t.price) as comparison_price
from mytable t
outer apply (
    select *
    from (
        select t1.*,
            row_number() over(partition by geography, product order by price desc) rn
        from mytable t1
        where t1.geography = t.geography and t1.product = t.product and t1.week <= t.week
        order by t1.week
        offset 0 rows fetch first 13 rows only
    ) x
    where x.rn = 2
) x
```

Comment: In the case of only one week of data, the where clause will exclude the source row. Instead, filter to the second value Inside the lateral query, and use OUTER APPLY?

Comment: @MatBailie: yes, you are right, thank you. I got distracted somehow while typing the query. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A lateral join is the way to go.  I would phrase it as:

```
select t.*, t2.price as comparison_price
from t outer apply
     (select distinct t2.price
      from (select top (13) t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.geography = t.geography and
                  t2.product = t.product
                  t2.week <= t.week
            order by t2.week desc
           ) t2
       order by t2.price desc
       offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only
      ) t2;
```

Comment: Needs to be OUTER APPLY in case of the correlated sub-query only returning one row, and the offset/fetch thus returning zero rows?